# ошибка синтаксиса Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

разворачиваю проект на VDS сервере. Отладчик выдал ошибку скрипте jquery: ***SyntaxError: '*,:x' is not a valid selector***.
строка выглядит так:

```
 t.querySelectorAll("*,:x")
```

в js jqury только начал вникать, особо пока ничего не понятно, так, что попроще плиз)

Comment: `"*,:x"` а вы сами тут что ищете?

Comment: дак это и не jquery, а обычный js

Comment: я проект переношу только я и сам толком не разобрался, что эта строка делает.из доки понял что селекторы css ищет, а "*,:x" я так понимаю, что-то типа регулярного выражения

Comment: [Document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: метод принимает валидный `css` селектор, регулярка это не валидный `css` селектор, нооо у вас на продакшене может быть все таки `jquery` используется?

Comment: потому что `jquery` может принимать в качестве селектора регулярку

Comment: на этом сервере тоже jquery есть и работает. Проверенно.